# AngularJS Dynamic Ng Model That Goes Back To Scope Variable

Tags: angularjs

My HTML and Ng-Repeat:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="product in myData">
<div class="col-sm-3">
@{{product.Name}}
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
@{{product.PriceWholesale|currency}}
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<input ng-model="product.Name['Monday']"></input>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<input ng-model="product.Name['Tuesday']"></input>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<input ng-model="product.Name['Wednesday']"></input>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<input ng-model="product.Name['Thursday']"></input>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<input ng-model="product.Name['Friday']"></input>                   
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<input ng-model="product.Name['Saturday']"></input>
</div>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
$scope.HoneyWholeWheat =  {
Monday:0,
Tuesday: 0,
Wednesday: 0,
Thursday: 0,
Friday: 0,
Saturday: 0
}
```

How can I get the ng-model to put `0` in the input for `product.Name['Monday']` where the product name is `Honey Whole Wheat`?

In other words, the `product.Name` part of the model should register as `Honey Whole Wheat` (I believe it automatically trims the spaces making it `HoneyWholeWheat` and then the `['Monday']` should be the string `Monday` making it connect back to `$scope.HoneyWholeWheat.Monday`?

But it doesn't and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Edit: The `@` is because I use Laravel for the view rendering, and Laravel also uses `{{}}` so I need the `@` to let Laravel know to let Angular do its thing.

Comment: Can you provide a plnkr?

Comment: Does $scope.myData exist?

Comment: @EfeOmoregieElijah yep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too dangerous mapping variables to your $scope directly like so, so i suggest declaring an internal property to store the instances

```
$scope.Data = {};//note the {}
```

I'm assuming you're receiving $scope.myData from somewhere, so all you have to do is map it into $scope.Data

```
angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(data) {
    $scope.Data[data.Name.replace(/\s+/g, '')] = {
        Monday: 0,
        Tuesday: 0,
        Wednesday: 0,
        Thursday: 0,
        Friday: 0,
        Saturday: 0
    };
});
```

The above code will map $scope.myData to $scope.Data so that you can have access to $scope.Data.PRODUCTNAME.Monday

Your HTML could become

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="product in myData">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    @{{product.Name}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    @{{product.PriceWholesale|currency}}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input ng-model="Data[product.Name].Monday" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input ng-model="Data[product.Name].Tuesday" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input ng-model="Data[product.Name].Wednesday" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input ng-model="Data[product.Name].Thursday" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input ng-model="Data[product.Name].Friday" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input ng-model="Data[product.Name].Saturday" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated $scope.Data[data.Name.replace(/\s+/g, '')] to trim whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to Efe's answer, ng-model doesn't evaluate the product name then continue with the property. It will look for the property 'Monday' in the object product.name.

The Angular [doc for ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) mentions that:

> Note: ngModel will try to bind to the property given by evaluating the expression on the current scope. If the property doesn't already exist on this scope, it will be created implicitly and added to the scope.

So Angular will try to add the 'Monday' property to the product name. But as it is a string (in your case, "Honey Whole Wheat"), the ng-model will return an error "Cannot create property 'monday' on string "Honey Whole Wheat".